# Show an h5 tag that matches a data-id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple data-id to a class. I need to select a particular h5 that ID matched a parent ID.

All that I am looking for is to select a specific h5 tag that data-id matches the Parent ID (`var ParentID = $('#ddlSearch option:selected').val();`)
Then I can traverse the hierarchy from there.

```js
$("#btn-search").click(function() {

  var ParentID = $('#ddlSearch option:selected').val();
  var selectedlastChild = $('.to-list).attr("data-id");  
  $('.list-container').each(function() {

    var delimiter = 'Id-';
    var ids = this.id.split(delimiter)[1];
    if (ParentID(399) === ids(399)) {
      if(selectedlastChild(399) ==ParentID(399))
     {
       show only <h5 class="to-list primary  data-id="399"> for example 
     and hide the rest
    }


  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h5 class="to-list primary  data-id="399">
    
<h5 class="to-list primary  data-id="392">
    
<h5 class="to-list primary  data-id="402">
```

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. You are correct my question was not properly asked. I made my question too complicated hence the reason, I am not getting help. I am going to edit the question again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for because there is relevant pieces of the code missing - ex., what is `#ddlLastChildSelected`?. Maybe this can help get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/muhc0b6s/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. The #ddlLastChildSelected point to the class #to-list and that is the class for the h5. I have edited the question to correct it.

Comment: I have looked at your jsfiddle and it is close to what I am looking for but instead of changing the colors, I want to show only the h5 that matches the parentId and hide the rest. I tried  $(`[data-id="${parentId}"]`).show(); and it doesn't work

Comment: That was an example. Showing/hiding is easy. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/p4bzcdqf/

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been pulling me hair for days. Now I can proceed

Comment: I want to make it as answered but I don't see the button to do that. I will come back to it later

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The class attributes do not have their closing quotes. The JavaScript suffers from a similar problem. There is also not enough HTML to support the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the `parentId`, you can use a selector like `[data-id="${parentId}"]` to select the `<h5>` you wish to change. If showing/hiding is your objective, you can use jQuery's [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method with a predicate utilizing the selector to determine whether to show or hide each element.

```js
$("#btn-search").click(function() {   
  const parentId = $('#ddlSearch option:selected').val();
    
  $('[data-id]').each(function () {
    $(this).toggle($(this).is(`[data-id="${parentId}"]`));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="to-list primary" data-id="399">One</h5>
<h5 class="to-list primary" data-id="392">Two</h5>
<h5 class="to-list primary" data-id="402">Three</h5>

<select id="ddlSearch">
  <option value="399">399</option>
  <option value="392">392</option>
  <option value="402">402</option>
</select>

<button id="btn-search" type="button">Search</button>
```